# Laravel database connections

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5. I see Laravel uses `.env` to connect databases for example `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD`, but i want to log in and use my username and password from my form to connect with those values from withim my oracle database with a table name "dba_users" which has the user and password and some others fields

i want to do that becauses each user has their own granted permissions(roles) to certain tables, thus Oracle would managed the user login permissions and not the `.env` `DB_USERNAME`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real term or question title for this would be "Dynamic Laravel Database Connections" on multi-tenant application. If you google about it you will find a lot of code like this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/set-up-dynamic-database-connection-globally

Comment: @Daniel glad it helped. Mind giving a vote up for the answer ☺️